# On the inequality $\frac{1+p(1)+p(2) + \dots + p(n-1)}{p(n)} \leq \sqrt {2n}.$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, contest-math, integer-partitions

> For all positive integers $n$, $p(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ as the sum of positive integers (the *partition numbers*); e.g. $p(4)=5$ since 
>   $4=1+1+1+1=1+1+2=1+3=2+2=4.$
>
> Prove that: $\dfrac{1+p(1)+p(2) + \dots + p(n-1)}{p(n)} \leq \sqrt {2n}.$

This problem is from a Turkish contest. Maybe it's a well known result.
More information about the *partition numbers* can be found at 
[OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000041).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [partition function formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function_formulas).

Comment: The result follows by induction given if you can prove $\frac{p(n+1)}{p(n)} \geq \frac{\sqrt{2n}+1}{\sqrt{2n+2}}$. This result does follow from the Hardy–Ramanujan asymptotical approximation for $p(n)$ (for large $n$), however this is highly overkill for a contest problem and not a very elegant solution imo so I'm sure there must be a simpler more elementary way of proving this.

Comment: My poor English made me misunderstand the comment of Winther. I deleted the wrong solution had given.

Comment: By Hardy-Ramanujan the ratio is asymptotic to $\sqrt{6n}\,/\,\pi$,
so $\sqrt{2n}$ is too large but only by a constant factor
$\pi / \sqrt{3} = 1.8138\!-$.  So a proof cannot be too generous
with intermediate inequalities...

Comment: It's Turkey IMO team selection test, year 2003.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We give a proof of the strict inequality
$$
\frac{1 + p(1) + p(2) + \cdots + p(n-1)}{p(n)} < \sqrt{2n}.
$$
The square root arises by first proving an upper bound
$(k-1)/2 + (n/k)$ for any integer $k \geq 1$, and then minimizing over $k$;
this kind of thing is seen often in analysis, but isn't a common tactic
in the inequalities that appear in competition math.

It is convenient and natural to extend the definition of $p(n)$
to all integers by setting $p(n) = 0$ for all $n < 0$ and $p(0) = 1$.
In particular, the numerator $1 + p(1) + p(2) + p(3) + \cdots$
in the fraction of interest is
$$
s_1 := \sum_{n' < n} p(n') = \sum_{m=1}^\infty p(n-m).
$$
Then for all $n$ the $p(n)$ partitions of $n$ can be identified with
solutions of
$$
n = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i a_i = a_1 + 2 a_2 + 3 a_3 + 4 a_4 + \cdots
$$
in nonnegative integers $a_i$ that vanish for all but finitely many $i$.
(Each $a_i$ is the number of times that $i$ occurs in the partition.)
Of course $p(n)$ is the sum of $1$ over such solutions $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$.
The first key point is:

**Lemma 1.** *$s_1$ is the sum of $a_1$ over
partitions $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$ of $n$.*

This can be proved using generating functions, or combinatorially from

**Lemma 2.** *$p(n) - p(n-1)$ is the number of
partitions $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$ of $n$ with $a_1 = 0$.*

*Proof*: The partitions with $a_1 > 0$ are in bijection with the
partitions of $n-1$ by $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots) \mapsto (a_1-1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$.
$\Box$

(**Corollary 1**:
*$p(n) \geq p(n-1)$ for all $n$, with equality **iff** $n=1$.*)

Now Lemma 1 can be proved by bijecting, for each $m$, the
partitions of $n$ with $a_1 = m$ with partitions of $n-m$ with $a_1=0$,
and summing over $m$.

The next point is to generalize Lemma 1 to a formula for the sum of
$a_i$ over partitions of $n$:

**Lemma 3.** *For $i \geq 1$ define
$$
s_i := \sum_{m=1}^\infty p(n-im).
$$
Then $s_i$ is the sum of $a_m$ over partitions $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$ of $n$.*

*Proof* as before, generalizing Lemma 2 to: $p(n) - p(n-i)$ is the number of
partitions $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$ of $n$ with $a_i = 0$. $\Box$

**Lemma 4.**  $\sum_{i\geq 1} i s_i = n p(n)$.

*Proof*: By Lemma 3 $\sum_{i\geq 1} i s_i$ is the sum,
again over partitions of $n$, of $\sum_i i a_i$, which is $n$. $\Box$

[**David Speyer** notes in a comment that this too can be obtained from the
generating function
$\sum_{n\geq 0} p(n) x^n = \prod_{i \geq 1} (1-x^i)^{-1}$,
here by applying the operator $x \frac{d}{dx}$.]

**Corollary 2.**  *For any $k$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^k i s_i \leq n p(n)$.*

That's an inequality on a linear combination of $s_1,\ldots,s_k$.
To reach an inequality on just $s_1$, we use:

**Lemma 5.** *For all $i\geq 1$ we have $s_1 + p(n) \leq i(s_i + p(n))$.*

*Proof*: Note that $s_i + p(n) = \sum_{i \geq 0} p(n-im)$.  Hence

$ i (s_i + p(n)) = \sum_{i \geq 0} i p(n-im) $

$ \phantom{i (s_i + p(n))} \leq \sum_{i \geq 0}
   \bigl(p(n-im) + p(n-im-1) + p(n-im-2) + \cdots + p(n-im-(i-1) \bigr)$

$ \phantom{i (s_i + p(n))} = s_1 + p(n),$

using Corollary 1 in the middle step. $\Box$

Combining Lemma 5 with Corollary 2 yields
$$
np(n) \geq \sum_{i=1}^k i s_i \geq \sum_{i=1}^k (s_1 - (i-1) p_n)
= k s_1 - {k \choose 2} p(n),
$$
whence
$$
s_1 \leq \left( \frac{k-1}{2} + \frac{n}{k} \right) p(n).
$$
It remains to choose the integer $k$ so as to minimize the upper bound
$(k-1)/2 + (n/k)$.  The final lemma is elementary but takes some verbiage
to prove in full, and this post is already quite long,
so I'll leave it as an exercise:

**Lemma 6**: *The minimal value of $\frac{k-1}{2} + \frac{n}{k}$ over
integers $k \geq 1$ is attained **iff**
${k \choose 2} \leq n \leq {k+1 \choose 2}$.  This minimal value
is smaller than $\sqrt{2n}$ for all $n$.*

(Note that if $n = {\kappa \choose 2}$ then there are two choices of $k$,
namely $k=\kappa$ and $k = \kappa-1$; else the choice is unique.
For large $n$, the optimal value(s) of $k$ grow(s) as $\sqrt{n/2}$,
which is indeed where $k/2 + n/k$ attains its minimum of $\sqrt{2n}$.)

Combining Lemmas 6 with the inequality for $s_1$ (displayed below Lemma 5)
yields the desired inequality $s_1 / p(n) < \sqrt{2n}$, **QED**.

Comment: In the second line I believe it should be $p(n)=0$ for all $n<0$ instead of $p(0)=0$ for all $n<0$.

Comment: Wow. One observation which makes things more obvious to me: Lemma $4$ is the result of hitting the equation $\prod (1-x^k)^{-1} = \sum p(n) x^n$ with $x \frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: **Scientifica**: thanks, I'll fix this.  **David Speyer**:
I started out trying to use this identity but couldn't see where to
go with it until it came up again via the $s_i$.  I can still add 
the $x \, d/dx$ interpretation.

Comment: Fixed too soon before noticing another such typo:
Lemma 3, sum of $a_i$, not of $a_m$.  Will fix in the next round.

Comment: ... and "conversely" the sums over $i$ in Lemma 5 should be over $m$ ...

Comment: Thank you very much!
Your solution is really amazing.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies you're welcome :D